# Loading remote images in Phonegap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm building a phonegap application that loads a feed that has facebook profile pictures. When I run the app with my chrome browser on my computer, all the images load normally, but when I package it up and load it to my android, no images load outside of my own remote server.

I've added the following to my config.xml

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

and it has not helped. No image outside of my server loads.

Comment: How you load images? Generally only in Chrome cross-origin is not supported.. But you say the opposite.

Comment: Just using <img src="http://imagelocation.jpg" />